# Lucene, StringField gets tokenized when doc is retrieved and stored again?

Tags: lucene

### Background

I simply add one document to an index and close it (Lucene 5.5.0):

```
Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new StringField("isbn", "9900333X", Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new TextField("title", "The Art of Computer Science", Field.Store.YES));
w.addDocument(doc);
w.commit();
w.close();
```

- field `isbn` is stored and not tokenized (`StringField`)
- field `title` is stored and tokenized (`TextField`)

I can retrieve this document by its isbn, with:

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirctoryReader.open(index));
Query q = new TermQuery(new Term("isbn","9900333X"));
TopDocs td = searcher.search(q, 1);
```

Now, this works because `isbn` is not tokenized/analized.

### Issue

Let's take that same document that we just found and store it into a new index:

```
Directory index2 = new RAMDirectory();
IndexWriterConfig config2 = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
IndexWriter w2 = new IndexWriter(index2, config2);
Document d2 = searcher.doc(td.scoreDocs[0]);
w2.addDocument(d2);
w2.commit();
w2.close();
```

Now I reopen this index and search for the same isbn:

```
IndexSearcher searcher2 = new IndexSearcher(DirctoryReader.open(index2));
TopDocs td2 = searcher2.search(q, 1);
```

This won't find it.

**However**, the same example does work when the isbn is composed by only digits. Which makes me assume that it is being tokenized when stored, even though it was supposed to be a `StringField`. Indeed, if I use a `KeywordAnalizer` for the writer, rather than a `StandardTokenizer`, then it works again. But this isn't what I want, because then the `title` field won't be analyzed either. Also, if this were the issue, the first retrieval shouldn't have worked either

It looks like storing the document into a second index drops some of its fields' properties. Is this expected?
Unless I'm doing something wrong, that looks like a bug to me. That field has been created as not tokenized. It should stay the same no matter where the document gets stored.

**EDIT**
If I print the value of `fieldType()` in the first and second index, I get:

- stored,indexed,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS
- stored,indexed,**tokenized**,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS

**EDIT 2**
I concluded it's a bug. Bug report submitted: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-7171

Comment: have you experimented with creating another query too? I know queries are supposed to be reusable, but something to try

Comment: I'd say this is by design, the javadocs of `IndexReader#document(int)` read: `NOTE: only the content of a field is returned, if that field was stored during indexing.  Metadata like boost, omitNorm, IndexOptions, tokenized, etc., are not preserved.`. The `oal.index.FieldInfo` class also does not provide information whether this field was tokenized or not, so the TextField is used as basis: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/0843e95f0c6661eaa8db372deb06318da1cfe9d2/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/document/DocumentStoredFieldVisitor.java#L70-L71

Comment: Ouch! Thanks for finding it. I still believe it's a bug though (or design flaw). Unless there is some other mechanism to retrieve that information?

Comment: Yeah, you could argue that this is a flaw or a bug, let's see what the Jira issue reveals. ATM, you could implement you own `Codec` and `FieldInfosFormat` to populate the `attributes` map of `FieldInfo` before writing to store all the additional field information you need. Then you need a custom `StoredFieldVisitor` that can read these attributes to create the correct instance of `IndexableField`. You still have define your implicit field schema somehow and can't easily reuse the original fields from the document as you have indexed it.